# Why does Chrome send two http requests while Firefox sends one?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, http, favicon

Edit: So the second response is definitely a favicon.ico issue but why does this happen in chrome and not firefox?

Original:
I'm learning express for node.js and practicing routing for Middleware. My issue is that the '/' route is getting through even though I'm not sending a request for it and I am not calling next(); in the Middleware before it. Also when I send a request to the '/' route it sends a double response. It does this in chrome and not firefox, so can someone explain the difference?

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

app.use('/users', (req, res, next) => {
    console.log('This handles /users route');
    res.send('<h1>This handles /users route</h1>');
});

app.use('/', (req, res, next) => {
    console.log('This handles / route');
    res.send('<h1>This handles / route</h1>');
});

app.listen(3000);
```

If I navigate to localhost:3000/users the page displays the html correct but the console logs:

- This handles /users route
- This handles / route

If I navigate to localhost:3000/ the page displays the html correct but the console logs:

- This handles / route
- This handles / route

Comment: Just do `console.log(req.url)` in your middleware and you can see what's going on.  You are probably seeing caching differences with favicon.ico between Firefox and Chrome.  But, if you add the log I mentioned, it will tell you for sure.  Remember that `app.use('/', ...)` matches every single request made to your server so it will always get hit unless something before it grabs the request.

Answer (score 3):

Chrome will request the site favicon.ico by default. like this:

http://localhost:3000/favicon.ico

[image: request]

[image: received]

Comment: Please make sure to always describe where the links you post lead to. `"enter image description here"` is not sufficient ^^